# ".p" files to be loaded recursively using AWS Glue / Athena

Tags: aws-glue

I need to load multiple Progress **.p** (extension) files by using AWS Glue (and Athena) but their format is not recognized.

The file structure is like below:

```
[START_FILE]

[STATUS]
OPEN=20240119235811
CLOS=20240120235808
POSDISCONNECTED=NO
CLOSE_TYPE=2
SWV=EUR:0064.0004
STID=0369
STNAME=XXXX XXXXXXXXXX
STADDRESS1=XXXXXXXXXXXX
STZIP=36089
STCITY=XXXXXXXXX
CODEPAGE=1252
FDATI=20240120232935
SDATI=20240120113922
REP_NR=506
ACC_REP_NR=1
NRPOSSES=1
[END_STATUS]

[HEADER_RECEIPT_INFO]
TXT1=         XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TXT2=            XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TXT3=           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TXT4=  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TXT5=          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
TXT6=****************************************
[END_HEADER_RECEIPT_INFO]

[VAT_INFO]
PRC1=4.00
PRC2=10.00
PRC3=16.00
PRC4=22.00
[END_VAT_INFO]
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks for any help